# Reload only jquery in page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I use jQuery and XAJAX at my page.
I have for example:

```
<span id="one">one</span>
<span id="two">two</span>
```

The page is successfully loaded and then I add an element with XAJAX:

```
<span id="one">one</span>
<span id="two">two</span>
<span id="three">three</span>
```

There is no page reload. But then the problem happends, and I can't click the new added item:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#one").click(function() {
           alert('one');
    }); // This works

        $("#three").click(function() {
           alert('one');
    }); // This doesn't working

});
```

How can I make it work, so I can click the added element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're adding things use the live method:

```
$("#three").live('click', function(){
    alert('three');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `live ()`.

`live()` will apply to dynamically added objects.

```
$("#three").live('click', function(){
    alert('three');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 1):

(ps.: i suggest you to create a .class to create a single .live()... otherwise you'll have to create a new live() for each new item...)

some like:

```
$(".numbers").live('click', function() {
    alert('one');
});
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very confusing. But I guess you just want live events:

```
$("#one").live('click', function() {
    alert('one');
});

$("#three").live('click', function() {
    alert('one');
});
```